# ListView, four values, only first one is fulfilled

Tags: android, listview

The MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView lista;
Context c;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    c=getApplicationContext();
    ArrayList<Seleccion> seleccion=new ArrayList<Seleccion>();
    seleccion.add(new Seleccion("David", "Fernández", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    seleccion.add(new Seleccion("Fernando", "Pérez", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    seleccion.add(new Seleccion("Antonio", "López", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    seleccion.add(new Seleccion("María", "Domínguez", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    ListaAdapter listAdapter=new ListaAdapter(c, seleccion);
    lista=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {


        }
    });
    lista.setAdapter(listAdapter);

}
}
```

The custom adapter:

public class ListaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private static int contador=0;
ArrayList<Seleccion>seleccion;
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

static class ViewHolder{
    TextView nombre;
    TextView apellido;
    int imagen;
}

public ListaAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Seleccion> seleccion) {
    Log.i("LISTA", "creating adapter");
    this.seleccion=seleccion;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("LIST", "Returned "+seleccion.size()+" results");
    return seleccion.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    Log.i("LIST", "one item returned, name: "+seleccion.get(position).getNombre());
    return seleccion.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){

        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitemlayout, null);
        contador++;
        Log.i("LIST", contador+" vews created");
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.nombre=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.apellido=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.imagen=R.id.imageView1;
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        Seleccion sel=(Seleccion)getItem(position);
        Log.i("LIST", "Name "+sel.getNombre());
        holder.nombre.setText(sel.getNombre());
        holder.apellido.setText(sel.getApellidos());
        holder.imagen=sel.getImagen();
    }

    return convertView;
}

}
```

The layout of the custom adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_alignTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the MainActivity layout...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I get four rows in the table, but only the first one is receiving the values. The other ones remain with the default text set in the adapter layout. I dont know where the error is...any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your getView to this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){

        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitemlayout, null);
        contador++;
        Log.i("LIST", contador+" vews created");
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.nombre=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.apellido=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.imagen=R.id.imageView1;
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
    }

        Seleccion sel=(Seleccion)getItem(position);
        Log.i("LIST", "Name "+sel.getNombre());
        holder.nombre.setText(sel.getNombre());
        holder.apellido.setText(sel.getApellidos());
        holder.imagen=sel.getImagen();

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same symptom but different cause for me. I changed my fragment layout to a controlled height instead of match_parent and that solves my issue.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

to

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```